# Need help calculating statistical power with a given sample size

Tags: statistical-power, post-hoc

I have a sample of about 7800 individuals that opted into a longitudinal panel survey from a larger register of about 40000 individuals. The data collected is concerns on a scale from 1 through 5 over repeated instances over the course of the past 9 months.

I know that there is a way to conduct a posthoc analysis on power using the sample size but am not sure which is the best option to use after looking at this site. https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html

I understand the basics of power and would appreciate some further explanation on how to go about this. Thank you!

Comment: Power is about performing a statistical test. Did you mention a test?

Comment: Hi @Bernhard, I performed a mixed-effects multilevel ordinal logistic regression on the full dataset, not sure if theres an analagous power calculation that goes with that.

Answer (score 1):

Power and sample size calculations are meant to be done before a trial or study based on expectations. Post-hoc power calculations are usually disliked because they are dependent on what you already found (so that assumes that is true now).

However, **power calculations for longitudinal data require number of time points, time duration, effect size, estimated variances, and the number of groups**. If you only have 2 time points, then you could structure this like an ANOVA and do a power calculation. If you only need a rough idea of power, then you can just take the first and last time point and use ANOVA. If this is a survey of only 1 group of people, then you can do a pre-post power calculation.

Package `longpower` in R has functions to do power calculations. If you want to do it by hand, then see Moerbeek & Terrenstra(2016) Chapter 9.Following their guidance, you can find power by comparing to the noncentral T distribution.

[image]
[image]